# Watir scraping sequential elements : so simple, but no

Tags: ruby, watir

This is so simple...
I want to scrap some web page like that with watir (gem of ruby:)

```
<div class="Time">time1</div> 
<div class="Locus">locus1</div>
<div class="Locus">locus2</div>
<div class="Time">time2</div>
<div class="Locus">locus3</div>
<div class="Time">time3</div>
<div class="Locus">locus4</div>
<div class="Locus">locus5</div>
<div class="Locus">locus6</div>
<div class="Time">time4</div>
etc..
```

The result should be an array like that :

```
time1 locus1
time1 locus2
time2 locus3
time3 locus4
time3 locus5
time3 locus6
time4 xxx
```

All the divs are at the same level (not imbricated).
No way to find the solution using the watir methods...
Thx for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each Locus element, you can retrieve the preceding Time element via the `#preceding_sibling` method:

```
result = browser.divs(class: 'Locus').map do |div|
  time = div.preceding_sibling(class: 'Time').text
  locus = div.text
  "#{time} #{locus}"
end
p result
#=> ["time1 locus1", "time1 locus2", "time2 locus3", "time3 locus4", "time3 locus5", "time3 locus6"]
```

Note that if the list is long, you may want to retrieve the HTML via Watir but then do the parsing in Nokogiri. This would save a lot of execution time, but at the cost of readability.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html) # where `browser` is the usual Watir::Browser
result = doc.css('.Locus').map do |div|
  time = div.at('./preceding-sibling::div[@class="Time"]').text
  locus = div.text
  "#{time} #{locus}"
end
p result
#=> ["time1 locus1", "time1 locus2", "time1 locus3", "time1 locus4", "time1 locus5", "time1 locus6"]
```

Comment: The way you pass the watir object is awesome.